# Email to case : issue to create the case

Tags: email2case

I have to work with an email to case but I didn't know much about that feature. 
I'm trying to send a email and watch the created case, but no case is created.

Here is the settings of the email to case : 
[image]

I tried to send an email at the first email adress (the small one) with an object and a body, but nothing happens, the case was not created.

How did that work ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set up email-to-case then you need to send email to the `Email Service Address` which is bigger one.

When at your exchange server, this `Email Address` (smaller one) and `Email Service Address` is mapped then sending email to smaller one, the case will get created.